# CSS "border-clip" halfway through border

Tags: html, css

I am following [this CSS turorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_boxes/Borders). On [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_boxes/Borders#Putting_this_all_together), it show how to use image borders. The result from following their tutorial is this result:[image: border image]

The tutorial used `background-clip: padding-box;` to make sure that the background did not go through into the border image. I want to know if I could somehow backgroung-clip *halfway* through the border, to give this result (edited with paint):[image]

Note I do **not** want this result, achieved by completely removing the background-clip declaration:[image]

EDIT:

`border-image-outset` seems promising, if only it could be set to a negative number.

EDIT 2:

Answers should work for situations where dimensions are not known -- for example if the `width` property is a %

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If border size is known, then you can use eventually `background-size`, `calc()`, and a gradient to draw te bg-color:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  line-height: 3;
  /*background-color: #f66;*/
  /*background-clip: padding-box;*/
  /* use instead : */
  background:linear-gradient(#f66,#f66) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: calc(100% + 20px)  calc(100% + 20px);
  text-align: center;
  /* border-related properties */
  border: 20px solid black;  
  border-image-source: url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/13060/border-image.png);
  border-image-slice: 40;
  border-image-repeat: round;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Border image</p>
</div>
```

borders of 20px are together 40px wide on each axis. `background-size` increased of 20px via `calc()` will cover only half of the borders areas.

Comment: @eeze , you will need javascript to find how much of the background-size has to added/taken off . background-clip-path does not exist (yet ?) ;)